# Excel VBA - call function without passing all the arguments

Tags: vba, excel

I have a public function

```
Public Function kuc_1(Mj, R1, R2, S, J1, J2)
```

Is it possible to call it without passing all the arguments,
for example:

```
kuc_1(1;5;5)
```

Comment: For your function, no. All arguments aren't optional. But if change your function to `Public Function kuc_1(Optional Mj, Optional R1, Optional R2, Optional S, Optional J1, Optional J2)` then you can omit all optional arguments.

Comment: Thanks, that's it

Comment: declare types from arguments. And second tip, once optional is used, you can add only optionals for next arguments.

Answer (score 3):

**Making use of** `Optional` **keyword to declare optional arguments**

To expound on my comment, you can assign `Optional Arguments` in a function like:

```
Public Function kuc_1(Optional Mj, Optional R1, _
                      Optional R2, Optional S, _
                      Optional J1, Optional J2)

    '/* your codes here */

End Function
```

To use the function, you can omit arguments you don't need like:

```
kuc_1(1;;2) '/* here you supply Mj and R2 and omit the rest of the arguments
```

<sup>**Note:** If your default separator is not semi-colon `;`, try using comma `,`. I used semi-colon since OP posted the sample usage using a semi-colon. In VBE though, you use comma `,`.</sup>

**Handling Optional Arguments**

In above code, we simply declared the arguments optional. It doesn't end there because we need to handle *optional arguments* within our code. Although it is optional, we would need to make it clear how the code runs if the optional arguments are supplied or not.

- **Check if optional arguments are supplied** - There are different ways to do this depending on the type of variable declared as `Optional`. For example, variables declared as `Variant` can be tested if supplied using `IsMissing` function. Consider below:

  ```
   Private Function cRept(text As String, number As Integer, _
                          Optional delimiter As Variant) As String

       cRept = Join(Split(String$(number, "."), "."), delimiter & text)
       cRept = Mid(cRept, Len(delimiter) + 1)

   End Function
  ```

Take note of the `Optional` variable `delimiter`. This code as is will generate a `Type mismatch error` if you do not supply the 3rd argument `delimiter` even if it is `Optional`. To handle this, we will use `IsMissing`.

```
    Private Function cRept(text As String, number As Integer, _
                           Optional delimiter As Variant) As String
        
        If IsMissing(delimiter) Then delimiter = ""
        cRept = Join(Split(String$(number, "."), "."), delimiter & text)
        cRept = Mid(cRept, Len(delimiter) + 1)
        
    End Function
```

Above code will now execute even if you supply `delimiter` argument or not. Below are additional ways to check depending on what type of optional variable you have:

```
    If a = "" Then a = "#N/A" '/* optional variable a declared as String */
    If a = 0 Then a = 1 '/* optional variable a declared as Integer */
    If a Is Nothing Then Set a = Application '/* optional variable a declared as Object */
```

- **Set default value for optional arguments** - You do this if you already know what to assign the optional argument in case it is not supplied.

  ```
   Private Function cRept(text As String, number As Integer, _
                          Optional delimiter As Variant = "") As String

       'If IsMissing(delimiter) Then delimiter = ""
       cRept = Join(Split(String$(number, "."), "."), delimiter & text)
       cRept = Mid(cRept, Len(delimiter) + 1)

   End Function
  ```

Above code will now run even if we omitted the check if it is supplied or not since we initialized the value of `delimiter` to `""` when we call the function and that argument is not supplied.

- **Calling functions with optional arguments** - Simplest is to omit the optional argument. Let us go back to OP's original function. Below is how we will call it in VBE and/or in Worksheet.

  ```
   kuc_1(1, ,2) '/* supplying Mj and R2 only */
   kuc_1(, , , , ,4) '/* supplying last argument J2 only */
  ```

When you use it in VBA (run in VBE), you make use of the syntax `<argument name>:=` to supply specific argument among many optional arguments. So last example above, can be written:

```
    kuc_1(J2:=4) '/* we specify what optional argument we are supplying */
```

<sub>**Disclaimer:** Function `cRept` above is for repeating a string just like the worksheet function `REPT`. The 3rd argument is really not necessary but used to demonstrate optional arguments.</sub>

Comment: The call to `kuc_1(1;;2)` just doesn't work as either a spreadsheet function or VBA call.

Comment: @Enigmativity Why is that, it works at my end. Of course that depends on on how your code is set up. Can you post the code you ran and failed? Also the `;` may not be your default separator. I use `,` on my end.

Comment: How does it work for you? When I type `kuc_1(1;;2)` or `kuc_1(1,,2)` in a `Public Sub` method it is a syntax error.

Comment: @Enigmativity It is hard to say without seeing your `kuc_1` function. If you can post it, please do and comment the link for me to check.

Comment: I have created a `Public Sub Foo()` in the same file as your `Public Function kuc_1` and then, within `Foo`, I try to call `kuc_1(1;;2)` and `kuc_1(1,,2)` and neither work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149068/discussion-between-l42-and-enigmativity).